# Adding a custom button to products-variation-list in article-display backend (see screenshot)

Tags: commerce

I added the functionality to duplicate product-variations, using the module commerce_product_clone and some custom functions to link the clone to the article-display after saving.

For convenient use, i need to add a clone-button to every product-variation in article-display @ node/{article-display-id}/edit :

[image: Edit article-display]

If clicked, the following URL should be called: /admin/commerce/products/{product-variation-id}/clone

I couldn't find any matching hooks or views for this...

We use Drupal 7.59 with Commerce-Kickstart 2.54.